# .net assemblies based database

Tags: .net, orm, база-данных

Одна из основных проблем при разработке серверных приложений - получения данных из базы и их маппинг на объекты. Почему бы не держать данные в таком виде, в котором исполняющей среде было бы с ними удобно работать? .net cборки можно динамически создавать, изменять, загружать и выгружать. Почему бы не распределить данные между несколькими сборками(на одной или нескольких машинах) и добавить над всем этим менеджер сборок? Конечно, понятно, что reflection работает на порядки медленнее чем обычные вызовы. На такую идею натолкнул язык Prolog, где были встроенные базы.

Comment: На эту тему обнаружил эту статью http://lightningtools.com/bcs/bcs-shims-net-assembly-as-a-data-source-for-business-connectivity-services/

Comment: Что-то не понимаю в чем собственно вопрос? Существует ряд известных ОРМ средств - они не подходят по каким-либо причинам? Зачем разносить доменные сущности между разными сборками и тем более подстраиваться под исполняемую среду?

Comment: Подобное решение мне не встречалось. Прежде чем кидаться и реализовывать нечто подобное для проверки этой идеи, хотелось услышать, что думают об этом остальные разработчики(если этого нет, возможно оно и не нужно?). В теории, подстройка под исполняющую среду может сделать ненужной Entity mappers, так как работа с сущностями будет производиться в том же виде, в каком они существуют в базе. Разнесение между сборками даст возможность ускорить поиск и распараллелить операции. Связанные сущности, которые выбираются обычно вместе, можно хранить в одной сборке.

Comment: Мое скромное мнение - бессмысленно. Возможно я не сталкивался с задачами, где это применимо и имеет смысл.
Кстате говоря статья ориентирована на шарапоинт, в котором работа с встроенной бд уже реализована по своему.

Comment: После разговоров со множеством разработчиков, пришло понимание, что идея несколько утопична, а Mappers не просто элемент, который можно выкинуть, а требуются для изоляции уровней. На данный момент начинаю искать языки и платформы, в которых код и данные объединены(ну кроме, ассемблера:) ). Кому-нибудь известно подобное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Лично я не вижу смысла в разделении сборок для этой задачи:

> - Если вы хотите иметь несколько возможных модельных представлений одних и тех же данных из базы, то организуйте *древовидную* или *параллельную* иерархию объектов и перенесите логику их построения в *фабрику*, которая и будет решать, какие объекты создавать.
> - Разные сборки и их динамическая подгрузка при таком подходе, понятно, не нужны.

- Написать **корректный** менеджер сборок - это крайне сложная задача даже для опытного разработчика, поэтому ценность такого подхода представляется довольно сомнительной.